# 「アプリに、漏洩した Google Cloud Platform（GCP）API キーが含まれている」警告アラート

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-console

AndroidアプリをリリースするためConsoleにファイルを上げたら、セキュリティと信頼性タブで「アプリに、漏洩した Google Cloud Platform（GCP）API キーが含まれています。」というエラーが発生してしまいました。

https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9287711
ここリンクの2を参考にAPIキーを制限したのですが、エラーは解消されません。

アプリ側で何か修正が必要な個所などあるのでしょうか。

Comment: 当該ヘルプページには「注: API キーに制限を追加済みの場合は、この警告を無視してください。」とあるようです